# Insert Value Based On Previous Rows When Using Table Parameter For Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update column value based on previous row with condition when using table type parameter to insert record.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Crud_StockTransaction]
    (@p_StockTransaction UDT_StockTransaction READONLY)   -- table-valued parameter
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StockTransaction (TransactionType, TransactionId, TransactionItemId, OpeningQuantity, ClosingQuantity)
        SELECT 
            TransactionType, TransactionId, TransactionItemId,
            (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(ClosingQuantity, 0)
             FROM StockTransaction 
             WHERE TransactionType = A.TransactionType AND TransactionItemId = A.TransactionItemId),
            --OpeningQuantity,
            CASE A.TransactionType 
               WHEN 1 
                  THEN ((SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(ClosingQuantity, 0) 
                         FROM StockTransaction 
                         WHERE TransactionType = A.TransactionType 
                           AND TransactionItemId = A.TransactionItemId) + A.Quantity)
                WHEN 2 
                   THEN ((SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(ClosingQuantity, 0) 
                          FROM StockTransaction 
                          WHERE TransactionType = A.TransactionType 
                            AND TransactionItemId = A.TransactionItemId) - A.Quantity)
            END,
            --ClosingQuantity,
        FROM 
            @p_StockTransaction

END
```

This seems to be complex, is there any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `ORDER BY` with your `TOP 1` to select the correct row. You also don't need to repeat the expression three times.

You could use

```
INSERT INTO StockTransaction
            (TransactionType,
             TransactionId,
             TransactionItemId,
             OpeningQuantity,
             ClosingQuantity)
SELECT TransactionType,
       TransactionId,
       TransactionItemId,
       OpeningQuantity,
       CASE A.TransactionType
         WHEN 1
           THEN OpeningQuantity + A.Quantity
         WHEN 2
           THEN OpeningQuantity - A.Quantity
       END AS ClosingQuantity
FROM   @p_StockTransaction A
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ClosingQuantity
                                   FROM   StockTransaction ST
                                   WHERE  ST.TransactionType = A.TransactionType
                                          AND ST.TransactionItemId = A.TransactionItemId
                                   ORDER  BY ST.TransactionId DESC /*??*/), 0)) CA(OpeningQuantity)
```

You should also consider concurrency. This will need additional locking hints if it may be called in parallel for the same `TransactionType, TransactionItemId` (and you will need to ensure there are no duplicates for this in the input TVP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll consider the concurrency thing.
 if i can use triggers for the same or that will be worse?

Comment: `(and you will need to ensure there are no duplicates for this in the input TVP)`. What to do if i am passing duplicates?

Comment: Triggers won't either help or hinder the concurrency issue - you will still need to use locking hints or isolation levels to ensure correct results. If you pass duplicates you need to take into account that the `OpeningQuantity` for all of them will be the state of the top 1 row before any rows have been inserted. So you will need to use window functions and running totals to get the correct opening quantity for rows after the first one.